# Set schema in MsSQL

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, mssql-jdbc

I use MsSQL and Spring Batch. I need to interact with two schemas in the same database. However, the driver for some reason ignores the installation of the scheme and uses one of the standard schemes. How can I fix this?

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource targetDataSource() {
        SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = getSimpleDriverDataSource();
        dataSource.setSchema("target");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource sourceDataSource() {
        SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = getSimpleDriverDataSource();
        dataSource.setSchema("source");
        return dataSource;
    }

    private SimpleDriverDataSource getSimpleDriverDataSource() {
        SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClass(com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.class);
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=myDB");
        dataSource.setPassword("myPassword");
        return dataSource;
    }
```

Code for writhing:

```
    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer() {
        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Person>()
                .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
                .sql("INSERT INTO target.people (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName)") //TODO убрать схему
                .dataSource(targetDataSource())
                .build();
    }
```

When remove `target.` part, there will be a `PreparedStatement Callback exception; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name) VALUES (?, ?)]; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Invalid object name 'people'.`  The same thing happens with reading from the schema. As soon as I remove the schema name from the request, I get an exception

Comment: If you're asking how to change the *default* schema, you need to `ALTER` the `USER` object being used and change the `DEFAULT_SCHEMA` setting.

Comment: I need to use a single user to work with two schemas

Comment: Then define the schema in the statements, @R1zen . A `USER` can only have 1 default schema.

Comment: I don't need the default schema. I need to be able to read and write from different schemas. MsSQL doesn't allow this?

Comment: *"MsSQL doesn't allow this?"* yes it does, like i said, "Then define the schema in the statements". You should be using 2 part naming by default anyway, so if you have multiple schemas this even more cements you should be doing so.

Comment: Don't remove the schema name from the statements if it works that way :)